# $\mathbb{R}G$-modules with the same characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. I'm looking for two nonisomorphic $\mathbb{R}G$-modules $U$ and $V$ with the same characters. Could someone provide an example?

Comment: If you mean finite-dimensional modules, then fat chance. A finite-dimensional representation of a finite group over a field of characteristic $0$ is uniquely determined (up to isomorphism) by its character. This is proven in Corollary 4.2.4 of [Pavel Etingof et al., *Introduction to representation theory*, AMS 2011](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/books.html) when the field is algebraically closed. When the field is not algebraically close, you need to additionally use the fact that two representations that become isomorphic over the algebraic closure must already ...

Comment: ... be isomorphic over the original field (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243669/the-noether-deuring-theorem ).

Comment: @darijgrinberg is right about what happens over a field of char. 0, but I would like to add that this question becomes very interesting if $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SteveD is that known in those cases?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I don't know. Instinctively, problems over $\mathbb{Z}$ are much harder. Anyway, I thought it was interesting because it seemed hard, and I didn't know the answer :)

Comment: @SteveD Ahh! I looked around and found another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895105/12952) which helps out.